# Docker Daemon not running on windows 11

Tags: docker, docker-daemon

I am a beginner into Docker stuff, I am on windows 11 and whenever I try to open docker desktop it doesn't open.
[image]
Always this error message shows up, also whenever I try to run `docker ps` or `docker images`
or anything related to docker it always shows this error
[image]
can anyone help

I have turned on hyper-v, wsl etc but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is followed by [`docker/for-win` issue 12413](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12413), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71093946/6309) (which suggests a fresh installation of Windows 11 itself!)

Only [workaround](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12413#issuecomment-1059974205=) so far (to avoid reinstalling W11):

> I tried reinstalling a couple times and different versions and nothing worked, the UI would just never show up.
>
> The only solution really was to delete `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Docker` and `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Docker Desktop`.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, tried to get assistance from docker support and did lota google but nothing worked.
I had a gut feeling that the issue was not within the Docker Desktop as i have tried all the options including deleting docker appdata etc. sov, i started investigating WSL and noticed the distros docker-desktop-data, docker-desktop was in stopped & uninstalling state. These states never changed and appears even after uninstalling Docker desktop and windows reboot.

PowerShell (admin)

```
wsl -l -v
```

I removed those distros after uninstalling docker desktop completely (including deleting docker folders from appdata manually)

PowerShell (admin)

```
wsl --unregister "DistributionName"
```

Replacing `"DistributionName"` with the name of your targeted distribution will unregister that distribution from WSL so it can be reinstalled or cleaned up. ***Caution:*** ***Once unregistered, all data, settings, and software associated with that distribution will be permanently lost***. Reinstalling from the store will install a clean copy of the distribution. For example, `wsl --unregister "DistributionName"` would remove `"DistributionName"` from the distributions available in WSL. Running `wsl --list` will reveal that it is no longer listed.

PowerShell (admin)

```
wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data

wsl --unregister docker-desktop
```

Finally, reinstalled Docker desktop and its associated applications.
It started working perfectly!

Comment: THANK YOU!
You saved my dev environment! I thought I was gonna go crazy deleting the APPDATA\Docker folder like literally every other google result says, and only this solution ACTUALLY HELPED ME!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue with Windows 10 and Docker Desktop 4.16.3 (96739)
I had disabled WSL2 based engine.

Just executed below command using Power shell( admin):

```
wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data

wsl --unregister docker-desktop
```

And my issue got solved like snap of finger.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the solutions listed here and nothing worked for me, i simply reinstalled wls2 from windows app store. and everything worked fine for me.